# Outlook 2016 Shortcut to jump to "Favorites->Incoming Email" or "Favorites->Sent Objects" etc

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I would like to to jump into "Favorites->Incoming Email" etc. How can I accomplish that. Macro would be fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, I'm afraid there is not a build-in method for this. If you'd like a Macro, it is suggested to go to Outlook for developer forum for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to switch to (select) a couple of often used Favorite folders. Below I show using [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). See the script below, followed by an annotated screenshot.

This does rely upon window coordinates, which are of course fragile. That is only an issue if you are moving Favorites around in the order (which is not the case in my Outlook usage). As shown in the script, I've chosen to use the following keys:

1. <kbd>u</kbd> == Show the Unread Mail Favorite
2. <kbd>i</kbd> == Show the Inbox Favorite

Note that these are single key presses, not using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> etc.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

; Allow rerunning this script by double-clicking on this file in the
; Windows Explorer to Reload it, versus the cumbersome process of
; having to right mouse click on the tray icon and select Reload:
#SingleInstance Force

SetTitleMatchMode 2 ; allow partial match to window titles

; Hotkeys for Outlook
;
;   Reference material used in this implementation:
;     https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/38389-archiving-email-in-outlook-with-a-single-keystroke/
;

; As best I can tell, the window text 'NUIDocumentWindow' is not present 
; on any other items except the main window. Also, I look for the phrase
; ' - Outlook' in the title, which will not appear in the title (unless 
; a user types this string into the subject of a message or task).
#IfWinActive - Outlook ahk_class rctrl_renwnd32, NUIDocumentWindow
  i::SelectFavoriteInbox()
  u::SelectFavoriteUnreadMail()
#IfWinActive

SelectFavoriteInbox() {
  ScopedMouseClick(48, 269)
}

SelectFavoriteUnreadMail() {
  ScopedMouseClick(48, 297)  
}

ScopedMouseClick(click_x, click_y) {
  ; Save off current mouse coordinates to restore them afterwards:
  MouseGetPos, curr_x, curr_y

  ; Move mouse cursor:
  MouseMove, %click_x%, %click_y%

  ; Click left mouse button:
  Click, Left

  ; Restore mouse coordinates
  MouseMove, %curr_x%, %curr_y%
}
```

[image: Annotated Screenshot]